# Integrate Apache Fuseki in Apache Tomcat and run SPARQL queries from Java Servlets

Tags: java, tomcat, sparql, fuseki

I would like to know if it is possible to integrate Apache Fuseki into Apache Tomcat and be able to run SPARQL queries directly from Java servlets or JSPs.
Is it possible to do so? How do I need to configure tomcat so to be able to do that?
Is there any tutorial that can help understand ontologies and how to integrate them in Java Servlets?

Answer (score 0):

To make SPARQL calls to a triplestore from a servlet or JSP, you need the client code - for example, RDFConnection. Fuseki is the server-side.

Apache Jena supports any triplestore that provides the standard SPARQL protocol.

You can run Fuseki in Tomcat (there's a WAR file) if you wish. Use the same client code. It is just a case of giving the code the right URL for the SPARQL endpoint.

You can run Fuseki separately with Tomcat as the business logic layer and
Fuseki as the database layer in a 3-tier architecture.

You call also embed the database in your webapp of servlets/JSPs. That's using TDB directly in your webapp. It is what Fuseki itself does.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you point out some tutorial that does so?

Comment: The first part, calls from a servlet (RDFConnection) is normal use of Apache Jena in Java. Adding a WAR file to tomcat is "drop it in the webapps directory". (general comment - avoid JSPs - they are more trouble to develop)

Comment: Thanks. Can you provide some code snippet on how to setup a connection between a servlet and the fuseki server? Also some code snippet on how to run a query could be useful.